# Android - How to override Display Font Size Programmatically

Tags: android, android-fonts

my app UI was not good(increase text size) when user sets the display font size normal to large or huge. how to i sets my app into only normal default font size. i used `DP` instead `SP`  it works for only XML `Textview` not dynamic `TextView`

Comment: Did you set Text size for dynamically created items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the text size dynamically using the `setTextSize` method the default measurement unit is a scale-independent unit (sp). This is good practice for a very logical reason...accessibility, user preferences, etc. However, if you still insist in walking away from best practices (sometimes you need to) you can use a different overload of the [`setTextSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int,%20float)) method that takes a specific measurement unit as its first parameter, for example...

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24.0);
```

The first parameter is a [TypedValue constant](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) and the constant specified is a "density"-independent pixel which should scale well across devices with different screen densities.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  There's a reason for the increased font size-  its for people who are hard of sight.  Its better for them to have an ugly UI they can read than a pretty one they can't.  My mother can't read a word at the smaller text sizes.  Don't you want those people to be able to use your app?

Comment: I have to disagree, there are specific use cases when you wouldn't want to use scale-independent units, and for that reason Android provides developers with the flexibility to specify a different measurement unit when setting the text size

Comment: I disagree that there are any such good cases.  If text can't be read, its useless.  The user's ability to read trumps any amount of pretty looking design you want. Sorry, but there's no excuse to ever design especially to break accessibility.

Comment: Sorry mate, but you're really off the topic here. Breaking accessibility was never mentioned, needless to say text readability. You're kind of helping me lead to the obvious point when you said "If text can't be read"...what if it can? Off the top of my head, a good case is scaling a branding text such as the app name, if text is relatively short, big (expands across the whole screen width) and easy to read...why sacrifice the design and possibly usability when there's no need for it? Thanks God the Android Team had a more flexible thinking when designing the Framework

Comment: Simple-  the person who's coding around basic functions used by people with disabilities to be able to use their own hardware and software.  And the people who are ok with that.  Its why we have the ADA in the real world, maybe its time to include software in it too.